# How to delete files in a folder except for a few certain files

Tags: python, bash, shell

It's quite hard to explain personally but basically, I have this Python script that creates thousands of other copies of itself instantly when opened.However i want to add a sort of kill-code that remove all the copies but  not the original.#
The main file is called "RSV.py" and it's copies are called "RSV-" and then a random HEX code (with the ".py" extension on the end)
I apologise for not  having the code present, this is due to it being saved on a different system to which i'm writing this on.
All help is appreciated, and unless i didn't see it,this is not a duplicate.

Comment: As correctly stated by Nagavamsikrishna, this one is indeed very simple, but there is a basic approach for these kind of questions when it's not that simple: use your programming language (Python in this case) for creating a batchfile, which contains the `del <filename>` commands for all concerned files, check it and if correct, launch it.

Comment: The problem is that each copy has a different HEX code to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be remiss if I didn't say that Python is a lame way to handle directory maintenance. That said, who am I to tell a man how to delete his files. Try this...

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob('/tmp/RSV-*.py'):
    os.remove(file)
```

A-

P.S. Where was the code you tried to write? ...grin.

Comment: Lol, Somewhere else, The code doesn't seem to function. No syntax's or errors but nothing happens

Comment: Did you... update the path (the snippet that looks like '/tmp/RSV-*.py') with the directory your files are located in?

Comment: No.Just changed it to : ('c:\Users\omenp\Desktop\RSV-*.py'). and got a .... unicode error!

Comment: You will need to specify the path with `'c:\\Users\\omenp\\Desktop\\RSV-*.py'` or `'c:/Users/omenp/Desktop/RSV-*.py'`

Comment: Flip the slashes. Python always uses forward slashes even on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

`rm RSV-*.py` should do the trick on Mac or Linux

Comment: Thank you, however i am using Windows

Comment: unless there isn't a difference

Comment: Invalid Syntax to do with the name

Comment: You tagged your question `bash`. If you have bash on Windows then there probably isn't a difference, and you can use `rm RSV-*.py`

Comment: i did not tag bash actually,that was someone else, and to be honestly have no idea what it is

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stop the python script to create its immediate copies if they're not needed, then there is something wrong in the code itself which is creating them in the first place. However, if you want to just add a line to remove all the excess of python copies of your main script you can add a system call inside the main script to remove all the excess files that are created when the main script finishes its execution.

Here's a simple guide on how to do that. You can replace the used ls -l command with what Nagavamsikrishna mentioned if you are running on Linux/Mac, else just replace rm with del to run on windows.

[Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: No, the code Creates the copies automatically and this was done purposely. As mentioned i want to created a "kill-code" that (incertain scenarios) could delete every copy (basically, a manual fail-safe if all hell breaks loose).

Comment: That makes sense, may I know which scenario will be this special case? The thing is that with writing a killing script you need to have such a scenario defined. I suggest adding an argument in the script itself or writing a manual script with the link I provided and run it.

Comment: That certain scenario would be my computer being destroyed by said duplication script when misused

Comment: Then I think you need to limit the number of files that are generated from your script. The system might crash if files exceed the capacity of the system. I suggest either adding a catch block to throttle the number of files created, else you won't be able to run the deletion script to remove the excess files.

Answer (score 0):

This will delete all the copies except for the original:

```
import glob
import os
for file in glob.glob ('DIRECTORY'):
    os.remove(file)
```